# Qt creater can't show pointer type?

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt creator to debug my c++ program, However, I found that the pointer type variables were shown as non-pointer type, see image below:
[image]

for example, I have `double* ax_pb = global_data->ax_pb;` in my code, while the variable window show that it is a double type.

Is it a bug of Qt or I can change some setting to avoid this?

the Qt Version is 5.4.1 and operation system is Ubuntu14.04 LTS

and the image below shows the version of Qt Creator

[image]

Comment: Qt Creator version would be useful (Qt version probably has nothing to do with this, version of debugger might).

Comment: @hyde I just attached image shows Qt Creator version.

Comment: Qt Creator dereferences pointer variables in the debug view by default I think

Answer (score 2):

Choose your favourite:

**Dereferencing enabled**

[image: Dereferencing enabled]

**Dereferencing disabled**

[image: Dereferencing disabled]